# php set array value as key but array_combine() not giving expected results

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting an array with one of the child arrays removed with array_combine. I want to set the value of the array as the key. I am getting the same array size in both array_column($details,'id') and $details but the result ($arr1Temp) came out is not as expected whereby there is only the last array of $details arrays created.

> $arr1Temp = array_combine(array_column($details,'id'), $details);

### Code snippets

print_r of $details:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 1
            [session_id] => 1
            [start] => 2018-09-06 10:30:00
            [end] => 2018-09-06 11:30:00
            [id] => william
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [event_id] => 1
            [session_id] => 2
            [start] => 2018-09-15 10:30:00
            [end] => 2018-09-15 11:30:00
            [id] => william
        )

)
```

print_r of array_column($details,'id'):

```
Array
(
    [0] => william
    [1] => william
)
```

print_r of $arr1Temp:

```
Array
(
    [william] => Array
    (
        [event_id] => 1
        [session_id] => 2
        [start] => 2018-09-15 10:30:00
        [end] => 2018-09-15 11:30:00
        [id] => william
    )    
)
```

If the ids from $details are not the same, then the array result from array_combine is as expected.

Comment: because you have 2 `williams`. Read, http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php#111668

Comment: ah yes. we shouldn't have the same key. thanks!